# Dart 2 AngularDart how to config env vars in deployment environment?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I need to use different config values when deploying my application vs when in development. How to set this up with Dart 2 using `webdev serve` and `webdev build` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The build.yaml allow you to add config variable that are different in development than in production.

Here is an example of a build.yaml

```
targets:
  $default:
    sources:
      include: ["lib/**", "web/**"]
    builders:
      build_web_compilers|entrypoint:
        release_options:
         dart2js_args:
           - -Dhost=https://example.com
           - -DenableFeatureOne=true
```

Then you can get the value of host and enableFeatureOne by using:

```
final host = const String.fromEnvironment('host', defaultValue: 'http://localhost:8080');
```

So in development the host will be `http://localhost:8080` and in production after compiling with dart2js it will be https://example.com.
Same for enableFeatureOne.

release_options will be only used when compiled with the `build` command or with `pub run build_runner build  -o build --release`

Development config should be the default one since there is no way to pass different config value to ddc. A workaround is to make a GET request on a file with this value when your app start.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I appreciate it!

Comment: How to set the host value for dev in build.yaml instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: Note that only dart2js supports -D right now, so you can't pass those variables with `dev_options` unless you also use `compiler: dart2js`.